# Manipulating form data before inserting to database

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5.3

I'm working on an API, i'm getting form data from mobile app to storing it in database table `workers` i want to modify a columns `registration_id` data before storing it in database

in my controller i'm storing like this

```
public function store()
{
    Driver::create(input::all());

    return $this->respondCreated('Driver created successfully');
}
```

in my model i'm trying to change the `registration_id` value to something

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Driver extends Model
{
   use SoftDeletes;

   protected $fillable = [
                           'agent_id',
                           'registration_center',
                           'sponsor_name',
                           'event_name',
                           'registration_id',
                          ];

   protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public function modifyRegistrationId($registration_id)
    {   
        $this->attributes['registration_id'] = 'test';
    }   
}
```

But it is not working the original form value is inserting to database 
how do i change the `registration_id` to some other value

looking forward for much needed help

thank you

Comment: Are you calling the modifyRegistrationId() function before storing to database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an event to alter any data before save. Take a look at [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#events) . Here we are using `boot()` defining callback behavior:

```
class Driver extends Model 
{

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        self::creating(function($model){
            //before create, do this...
            $lastRegistrationId = Driver::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first()->registration_id;
            $this->registration_id = $lastRegistrationId.date('Y-m-d');
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

The functions you cand use are: creating, created, updating, updated, saving, saved, deleting,  deleted, restoring, restored

Comment: i really appreciate your time,  can you please tell me how to check the last `registration_id`,  append current date to it and insert to database thank you

Comment: Not sure what you want here. registration_id would be an INT type. If you append current date, would change to string/varchar. If you try to store will raise an error. What exactly you want to do?

Comment: registration_id is not `INT` its a string i just want to appent current date to it

Comment: Ok, edited.. You can format the date format as you wish. In my opinion you shouldn't use 'id' when dealing with varchar fields. It doesn't follow the Laravel convetion.

Answer (score 1):

If you'll always override the value, [define a mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator):

```
public function setRegistrationIdAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['registration_id'] = 'test';
}
```

If you want to do that just once, override the value:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->registration_id = 'test';
    Driver::create($request->all());

    return $this->respondCreated('Driver created successfully');
}
```

Comment: @ Alexey Mezenin  it works!! thank you so much i really appreciate it,  can you please tell me how to check the last inserted `registration_id`, increment it and append current date to it and insert to database thank you

Comment: @MrRobot you can set date with same `$request->date = Carbon::now()`, but it's better to use Laravel's `created_at` for this. To get an ID of inserted row do this `$id = Driver::create($request->all())->id;` instead of `Driver::create($request->all());`